# What if there are three less neutrons in $_{89}^{238}U$?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, radioactivity, neutrons

I am wondering what will happen if there are three less neutrons in $_{89}^{238}U$? I found this problem in a book. Will it produce $_{89}^{235}U$ or $_{92}^{235}U$?

The reason for choosing $_{92}^{235}U$ is I am thinking that three less neutrons mean that these neutrons are converted into three protons and three electrons and also the electrons are emitted from the nucleus through radiation. But I don't know is it correct or not. Any help from the community will be really appreciated.

Comment: There are just three fewer neutrons in the nucleus, that is all…

Comment: Oh! Thank you @JonCuster So radiation isn't a problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element 89 is actinium, not uranium.  If it doesn’t have exactly 92 protons, it is not uranium.

If you start with $\rm^{238}_{92}U$ and steal three neutrons, you get $\rm^{235}_{92}U$.

Some nuclei can undergo “beta decay,” in which a proton or neutron changes flavor.  In beta decay an electron (or antielectron) is emitted to conserve charge, and a neutrino (or antineutrino) is emitted to conserve the number of “leptons.” But U-238 does not undergo beta decay, because Np-238 is too heavy.  Instead, U-238 decays mostly by alpha emission to thorium-234.

Comment: Oh yes! I forgot to look at it.